# Unity Mock HMD not rendering with ARCore installed

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, arcore, virtual-reality

I am trying to create a mobile vr game with ARCore in Unity for positional tracking, and I can't get the Mock HMD to render. I tried the Cardboard SDK but it didn't work so I am trying to use Mock HMD. But it doesn't render and in the docs it says that there should be a setting to change to left eye or right eye in the game view but there is none. I have the package installed because I can change the eye and rendering mode on the camera, but it doesn't actually do stereo rendering.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no code, I just have Unity ARCore for Android with point clouds and plane tracking. I just followed the official Unity ARCore tutorial. I also have mock Hmd which doesn't render.